# How to change Android Tab Color in Titanium 5.2?

Tags: android, tabs, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Just upgraded to the latest SDK 5.2.0 (from 3.5.1) and Studio 4.5. For Android my action bar used to be styled using the AppCompat generator -> http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/  This didn't work when I upgraded, so I decided to try Material themes.

I would like to make the tabs on my tabgroup a different colour to the action bar.  I used to be able to do it, but the material theme constant "colorPrimary" seems to colour everything the same colour.  The only thing I can think of is to move away from tab group and create my own tab bar or something similar (really don't want to reinvent the wheel just to work around something this simple)

Comment: I don't know much about Android theming, but I also noticed some changes from 3.5 to 5+.
I'm using this https://github.com/ricardoalcocer/actionbarextras module to customize my action bar the way I want it

Comment: Had a look at this - although very nice and I'll keep it in mind for future projects - it doesn't allow changing of tab colours.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, always read through the major and minor [release notes](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_SDK_Release_Notes) when you upgrade to see what (breaking) changes there are.

In Titanium 4.0 [we switched](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_SDK_4.0.0_Release_Note-section-46239807_TitaniumSDK4.0.0ReleaseNote-MaterialTheme) to use the Material Theme, which makes it a lot easier to change the colors of your app.

Learn how you set the colors in our [Material Theme guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Themes-section-34636181_AndroidThemes-MaterialTheme).

Comment: Hi, I did read all the notes and even found your linked Theme Guide (nice to see the pics now loading).  None of your linked documents actually answer my question though. Being able to change the colour of tabs that appear under the action bar on Android.  I'm guessing that it can't be done with Material Theme.  That's OK as the theme is kinda growing on me.

Comment: My lead on question is why the indicator for selected tab is linked to the colour of activated controls. For instance if I make it White, then all swicthes when selected are white also .... but perhaps that is for another day ... and a Google question :).

Comment: Yep, that's a choice Google made with the Material Design theme. They wanted to make things more simplistic.